# How to fix Image scaling in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an application where I show some images. But when I'm displaying an ImageView, it expands the Parent Linear Layout.
How can i fix this?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/linearlayoutround"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/testimage" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:text="Admin" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/testtest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/testimage"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want this:

[image]

But displays this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use **android:adjustViewBounds** property

add this into **ImageView** like this:

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/testtest"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:src="@drawable/testimage"/>
```